# filter items from list of dictionary in c# based on matching key and values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, dictionary

I have list of Dictionary:-

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();   
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("name", "abc");
dict.Add("age", "22");
dict.Add("address", "xyz,aa");
dict.Add("contact", "111");
list.Add(dict);
Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict2 .Add("name", "pqr");
dict2 .Add("age", "25");
dict2 .Add("address", "xxx,bb");
dict2 .Add("contact", "4222");
list.Add(dict2);
Dictionary<string, string> dict3 = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict3 .Add("name", "aa");
dict3 .Add("age", "24");
dict3 .Add("address", "xxx,aa");
dict3 .Add("contact", "aaa");
list.Add(dict3);
```

In this list I want to find out those records which address contains 'aa'

Comment: so did you try anything in particular using `Linq` or standard loops? What's your issue?

Comment: you can like as list.Where(d => d.Values.Any(v => v.Contains("aa")));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a list of dictionaries where their address contains "aa"

```
list.Where(x => x["address"].Contains("aa"));
```

To ignore case-sensitivity

```
list.Where(x => x["address"].ToLower().Contains("aa"));
```

And this will give you a flatten list of records including just pair of key,value where key is "address" and value contains "aa"

```
list.Where(x => x["address"].Contains("aa")).SelectMany(y=>y.Where(item=>item.Key=="address"));
```

Comment: It throws an exception if there is `address` key in a dictionary

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski That's a basic assumption to have address in all the records. apart from that, it's easy to handle it as you know. Here we are talking about the way to retrieve that records. by the way, thank you, good catch.

Comment: first one worked for me, i needed all the list which key is address and value contains 'aa', thank you @MohammadNikrvesh

Comment: when i am entering 'Aa' it's not returning record, how to manage case sensitive searching

Comment: @shahbazusmani you need to use .ToLower() method before Contains(...)
I've updated my answer, You can find it out there.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) methods

```cs
var result = list.Where(d => d.Values.Any(v => v.Contains("aa")));
```

It returns you a two `Dictionary<string, string>` instances, containing values with `aa` inside.

If you need a filtered list for address key and value contains `aa`, the code below returns you a dictionaries with the such keys

```cs
var result = list.Where(d => d.ContainsKey("address") && d["address"].Contains("aa"));
```

This code returns the flattened sequence of key/value pairs for entire list

```cs
var result = list.SelectMany(l => l).Where(kv => kv.Key == "address" && kv.Value.Contains("aa"));
```

To perform case-insensitive search (as it stated in comments) `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` should be added to `Contains` method

```cs
var result = list.SelectMany(l => l).Where(kv =>
    kv.Key == "address" && kv.Value.Contains("Aa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: i need a filtered list which key is address and value contains 'aa'

Comment: List itself or dictionaries inside it?

Comment: @shahbazusmani I've updated my answer base on what you need (just list of addresses which contains 'aa')

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski your updated answer worked for me, but if i am searching like 'Aa', its not returning any record

Comment: @shahbazusmani you should add `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to `Contains` method, I've updated an answer